# Using Windows Shell (File Explorer) without Taskbar

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, taskbar

I'm currently trying to write an alternative piece of taskbar software (in Python) for better customisation, and one of the main stumbling blocks is disabling the taskbar. My app can sit over the taskbar perfectly well, but if the user presses the Windows Key or Ctrl+Esc, the Start menu pops up and the Windows taskbar comes to the front. Since the taskbar is controlled by `explorer.exe` I have looked up disabling Explorer, and found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/435275/can-you-disable-windows-explorer-from-starting-with-windows) solution to edit a registry key and change the Windows Shell, thus effectively disabling Explorer. The issue with this is, unsurprisingly, Windows Explorer (The file explorer) is also disabled. Now I could also try to make a custom Explorer, but I would ideally like a way to have File Explorer running without the Taskbar.

Tl;dr: I need to not have the Taskbar open by killing the Windows Explorer process, but also need the File Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

I happen to be having Windows 2000's source code. I just took a ***peek*** look at the `explorer` folder.

> `tray.c` -> Responsible for handling icons and system tray behavior.
>
> `task.c` -> Responsible for handling task bar functionality and behavior.
>
> `startmenu.cpp` -> Responsible for start menu functionality and behavior.

I'm definitely sure this hasn't changed much and that the taskbar is controlled by the `explorer` process.

Therefore what you are trying to achieve is not possible I believe.

**EDIT** : The files that I mentioned above were leaked online long ago and I happen to be having a copy just for my study purposes and in no way I ***endorse/encourage*** such leaks.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. I reckon I can probably just detect the shortcut keys and force my taskbar on top when they get received.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Haha, I love the disclaimer!